# my django server running at 127.0.0.1:8000/blog how to change become 127.0.0.1:8000

Tags: python, django

My Django server is running on `127.0.0.1:8000/blog`. How can I change this to become `127.0.0.1:8000`.

**url.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Where is your "/blog" url defined? Change it to "/". Should be in your app/urls.py file.

Answer (score 0):

edit url file

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from video.views import blog, login, register
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', blog, name='blog'),
    url(r'^login/', login, name='login'),
    url(r'^register/', register, name='register'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, I think it might be helpful to give some context about what the error was.